# Use of undefined constant num - assumed 'num' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Demo\practice4.php on line 12

Tags: php, function

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Practice4</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
            function calculate($number1,$number2)
            {
                $mult=$number1*$number2;
                define(num,$mult);
                return num;
            }
        echo "Number calculated is " . calculate(9,9);

?>
```

> Please help me out with this.I am newbie to php.May i know can i return a Constant from a function if yes,Why am i getting  *Use of undefined constant num - assumed 'num' .*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php), you will know that you have incorrectly used the syntax.

Check the following code:

```
function calculate($number1,$number2)
{
    $mult=$number1*$number2;
    define('num',$mult);
    return num;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first argument of `define()` is a string. You need to quote `num`:

```
define('num',$mult);
```

[define() definition](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php)